# How to set margins (padding) in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am inserting an image into an UITextView using an NSAttributedString, but the problem is that I want to set the top padding to a few points(2/3), so that the image y center will be on the [baseline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Art/glyphterms_2x.png) of the text.

Here is my code:

```
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:currentMessage];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
        textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[imagesArray objectAtIndex:count] CGImage] scale:4.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

        int newPos = [[imagesPosArray objectAtIndex:count] intValue];
        [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(newPos, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
        messageTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: You can set the size of the `NSTextAttachment`. And possibly its baseline